React Native Expo App crashes on Testflight when it starts up
When I published my build to the app store and tried to run it on TestFlight it immediately crashes. I have no idea where to look on how to fix the crash. The app runs smoothly when starting it in development mode, production mode, or regular expo go. (I do not have a macbook or mac, I solely use windows!) I took a look at the crash logs which were given but it all looks like a bunch of gibberish!
crash log (partial):
{"app_name":"somaticsFrontend","timestamp":"2024-06-03 10:27:11.00 +0100","app_version":"1.0.6","slice_uuid":"2f9799dd-2ebe-31cb-856c-8d6299923f22","adam_id":"6474644368","build_version":"1.0.6","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.somaticsfitness.somatics","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 17.5.1 (21F90)","roots_installed":0,"name":"somaticsFrontend","incident_id":"2FBC4B5C-8E8A-45A4-A5C9-5C5E1A44ED5C"}
{
  "uptime" : 340000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPhone14,4",
  "coalitionID" : 1770,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 17.5.1",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "21F90"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2024-06-03 10:27:11.5520 +0100",
  "codeSigningMonitor" : 2,
  "incident" : "2FBC4B5C-8E8A-45A4-A5C9-5C5E1A44ED5C",
  "pid" : 4197,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2024-06-03 10:27:11.2904 +0100",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 8227988368301,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 8227994625027,
  "procName" : "somaticsFrontend",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/F0D3E9B3-01F9-4CE0-8BC9-D4F229B2C143\/somaticsFrontend.app\/somaticsFrontend",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0.6","CFBundleVersion":"1.0.6","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.somaticsfitness.somatics","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"15F31e"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"6474644368","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"407A5B8A-CC6B-4067-8A38-1ED7F5648EA0","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"862342332"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.somaticsfitness.somatics",
  "crashReporterKey" : "12f8bc948b6a871bc349fbb2ea13664309ffd720",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "codeSigningID" : "com.somaticsfitness.somatics",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "4XC4U2WSSK",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570450689,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 5,
  "instructionByteStream" : {"beforePC":"fyMD1f17v6n9AwCRNez\/l78DAJH9e8Go\/w9f1sADX9YQKYDSARAA1A==","atPC":"AwEAVH8jA9X9e7+p\/QMAkSrs\/5e\/AwCR\/XvBqP8PX9bAA1\/WECeA0g=="},
  "basebandVersion" : "3.50.04",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":6,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Abort trap: 6","byProc":"somaticsFrontend","byPid":4197},
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":540448,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":90136,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":1449756,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1934300,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1936364,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":133140,"symbol":"__invoking___","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":129120,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invoke]","symbolLocation":428,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":614876,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":1666944,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1675384,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1674448,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":8508,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15828,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":46080,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":748,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":48944,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":380,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":93364,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":91432,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":404,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":18740,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4300,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11}],
  "faultingThread" : 2,
  "threads" : [{"id":2745059,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":4337937152},{"value":7},{"value":8578272521},{"value":5},{"value":15120},{"value":4339047856},{"value":0},{"value":4338826308},{"value":4339047864},{"value":18446744073709551600},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":12887632440},{"value":2095104},{"value":2043},{"value":3114481980},{"value":4338826308},{"value":4338826308},{"value":0},{"value":13},{"value":4337937145},{"value":8644888688,"symbolLocation":42824,"symbol":"InitialAllocationPool"},{"value":6132899200},{"value":0},{"value":15},{"value":0},{"value":10},{"value":1},{"value":7001442648,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"nominal type descriptor for Optional"}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":17743532727467710864},"cpsr":{"value":1610616832},"fp":{"value":6132898960},"sp":{"value":6132898832},"esr":{"value":2449473547,"description":"(Data Abort) byte read Access flag fault"},"pc":{"value":6999972420},"far":{"value":0}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":3988036,"symbol":"(anonymous namespace)::ForeignMetadataCacheEntry::matchesKey((anonymous namespace)::ForeignMetadataCacheEntry::Key)","symbolLocation":220,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3987744,"symbol":"std::__1::pair<swift::HashMapElementWrapper<(anonymous namespace)::ForeignMetadataCacheEntry>*, unsigned int> swift::ConcurrentReadableHashMap<swift::HashMapElementWrapper<(anonymous namespace)::ForeignMetadataCacheEntry>, swift::Mutex>::find<(anonymous namespace)::ForeignMetadataCacheEntry::Key>((anonymous namespace)::ForeignMetadataCacheEntry::Key const&, swift::ConcurrentReadableHashMap<swift::HashMapElementWrapper<(anonymous namespace)::ForeignMetadataCacheEntry>, swift::Mutex>::IndexStorage, unsigned long, swift::HashMapElementWrapper<(anonymous namespace)::ForeignMetadataCacheEntry>*)","symbolLocation":260,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3945840,"symbol":"swift::MetadataResponse performOnMetadataCache<swift::MetadataResponse, swift_checkMetadataState::CheckStateCallbacks>(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift_checkMetadataState::CheckStateCallbacks&&)","symbolLocation":1168,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3944660,"symbol":"swift_checkMetadataState","symbolLocation":36,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3601644,"symbol":"type metadata completion function for ClosedRange<>.Index","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3962736,"symbol":"swift::MetadataCacheEntryBase<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry, void const*>::doInitialization(swift::MetadataWaitQueue::Worker&, swift::MetadataRequest)","symbolLocation":772,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3892840,"symbol":"_swift_getGenericMetadata(swift::MetadataRequest, void const* const*, swift::TargetTypeContextDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*)","symbolLocation":2776,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3708488,"symbol":"__swift_instantiateCanonicalPrespecializedGenericMetadata","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":96248,"symbol":"_arrayConditionalCast<A, B>(_:)","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":96144,"symbol":"_swift_arrayDownCastConditionalIndirect","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3805344,"symbol":"tryCastToArray(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, bool, bool)","symbolLocation":216,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3801192,"symbol":"tryCast(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, bool, bool)","symbolLocation":992,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3802124,"symbol":"tryCast(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, bool, bool)","symbolLocation":1924,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3799828,"symbol":"swift_dynamicCast","symbolLocation":208,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":538664,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":539412,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":516616,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":517948,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1791856,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1792116,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":8508,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15828,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":75172,"symbol":"_dispatch_main_queue_drain","symbolLocation":988,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":74168,"symbol":"_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":354064,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":342292,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1996,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":339160,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4520,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":4237580,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":888,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":4975056,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":340,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":17420,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":249420,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2240,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":2745066,"frames":[{"imageOffset":4292,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6133460992},{"value":3847},{"value":6132924416},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6133460992},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8579006660},"far":{"value":0}}},{"triggered":true,"id":2745067,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":8578126531},{"value":6134032400},{"value":110},{"value":0},{"value":15470974812869043014},{"value":15470974809337156422},{"value":512},{"value":6134031168},{"value":0},{"value":2095104},{"value":16},{"value":0},{"value":328},{"value":6134034432},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":4099},{"value":6134034656},{"value":276},{"value":6134034656},{"value":12933802728},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":12907669632},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8579034124},"cpsr":{"value":1073745920},"fp":{"value":6134032256},"sp":{"value":6134032224},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8245982252,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":0}},"queue":"com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue","frames":[{"imageOffset":50220,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":31756,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":268,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":482208,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":180,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":85156,"symbol":"abort_message","symbolLocation":132,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":20060,"symbol":"demangling_terminate_handler()","symbolLocation":348,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":204332,"symbol":"_objc_terminate()","symbolLocation":144,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":82024,"symbol":"std::__terminate(void (*)())","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":81932,"symbol":"std::terminate()","symbolLocation":108,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":15848,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":46080,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":748,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":48944,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":380,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":93364,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":91432,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":404,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":18740,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4300,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11}]},{"id":2745068,"frames":[{"imageOffset":4292,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6134607872},{"value":4867},{"value":6134071296},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6134607872},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8579006660},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2745069,"frames":[{"imageOffset":4292,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6135181312},{"value":10243},{"value":6134644736},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6135181312},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8579006660},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2745071,"frames":[{"imageOffset":4292,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6135754752},{"value":9987},{"value":6135218176},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6135754752},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8579006660},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2745072,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","threadState":{"x":[{"value":268451845},{"value":21592279046},{"value":8589934592,"symbolLocation":136,"symbol":"th_td_attr"},{"value":71481140707328},{"value":1841356872},{"value":71481140707328},{"value":2},{"value":4294967295},{"value":18446744073709550527},{"value":16643},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":16643},{"value":4294967171},{"value":2043},{"value":2154031099},{"value":18446744073709551569},{"value":124},{"value":0},{"value":4294967295},{"value":2},{"value":71481140707328},{"value":1841356872},{"value":71481140707328},{"value":6136323448},{"value":8589934592,"symbolLocation":136,"symbol":"th_td_attr"},{"value":21592279046},{"value":21592279046},{"value":4412409862}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8245952520},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":6136323296},"sp":{"value":6136323216},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8245938184},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":6152,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":20488,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":20256,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":436,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":19808,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":343900,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":341504,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":339160,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":818764,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":818332,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":4318784,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":420,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":911128,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":732,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":24684,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4312,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11}]},{"id":2745073,"frames":[{"imageOffset":4292,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6136901632},{"value":17667},{"value":6136365056},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6136901632},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8579006660},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2745074,"frames":[{"imageOffset":4292,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6137475072},{"value":17923},{"value":6136938496},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6137475072},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8579006660},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2745075,"name":"com.facebook.react.JavaScript","threadState":{"x":[{"value":268451845},{"value":21592279046},{"value":8589934592,"symbolLocation":136,"symbol":"th_td_attr"},{"value":137451838373888},{"value":0},{"value":137451838373888},{"value":2},{"value":4294967295},{"value":18446744073709550527},{"value":32003},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":32003},{"value":718089},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":18446744073709551569},{"value":7153575928,"symbolLocation":56,"symbol":"clock_gettime"},{"value":0},{"value":4294967295},{"value":2},{"value":137451838373888},{"value":0},{"value":137451838373888},{"value":6138043832},{"value":8589934592,"symbolLocation":136,"symbol":"th_td_attr"},{"value":21592279046},{"value":21592279046},{"value":4412409862}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8245952520},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":6138043680},"sp":{"value":6138043600},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8245938184},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":6152,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":20488,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":20256,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":436,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":19808,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":343900,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":341504,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":339160,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":1542440,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":911128,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":732,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":24684,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4312,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11}]},{"id":2745076,"name":"hades","threadState":{"x":[{"value":260},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":160},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6138621608},{"value":0},{"value":12943215560},{"value":2},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":305},{"value":8831460600},{"value":0},{"value":12943215536},{"value":12943215600},{"value":6138622176},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":256},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8579016420},"cpsr":{"value":1610616832},"fp":{"value":6138621728},"sp":{"value":6138621584},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8245961164},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":29132,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":14052,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1228,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":54532,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":17},{"imageOffset":840328,"symbol":"hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::worker()","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":840176,"symbol":"void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v160006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct>>, hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::Executor()::'lambda'()>>(void*)","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":24684,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4312,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11}]},{"id":2745080,"name":"hades","threadState":{"x":[{"value":260},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":160},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6139195048},{"value":0},{"value":12943205160},{"value":2},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":305},{"value":8831460600},{"value":0},{"value":12943205136},{"value":12943205200},{"value":6139195616},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":256},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8579016420},"cpsr":{"value":1610616832},"fp":{"value":6139195168},"sp":{"value":6139195024},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8245961164},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":29132,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":14052,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1228,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":54532,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":17},{"imageOffset":840328,"symbol":"hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::worker()","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":840176,"symbol":"void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v160006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct>>, hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::Executor()::'lambda'()>>(void*)","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":24684,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4312,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4341317632,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "2e2c05f8-377a-3089-9ad9-1926d284dd03",
    "path" : "\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/libobjc-trampolines.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc-trampolines.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4351885312,
    "size" : 1916928,
    "uuid" : "3b8748f2-7356-360f-98e1-2903f0238b76",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/F0D3E9B3-01F9-4CE0-8BC9-D4F229B2C143\/somaticsFrontend.app\/Frameworks\/hermes.framework\/hermes",
    "name" : "hermes"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4333977600,
    "size" : 5046272,
    "uuid" : "2f9799dd-2ebe-31cb-856c-8d6299923f22",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/F0D3E9B3-01F9-4CE0-8BC9-D4F229B2C143\/somaticsFrontend.app\/somaticsFrontend",
    "name" : "somaticsFrontend"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6995984384,
    "size" : 5570560,
    "uuid" : "d9ad5cc1-ca2c-3f0a-8091-652b0df56d14",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/swift\/libswiftCore.dylib",
    "name" : "libswiftCore.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7153262592,
    "size" : 290816,
    "uuid" : "81d355df-266a-3010-bab8-113b76a206c1",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
    "name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7019941888,
    "size" : 5431296,
    "uuid" : "00e76a98-210c-3cb5-930b-f236807ff24c",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8176529408,
    "size" : 36864,
    "uuid" : "c19b2aeb-6aa8-3f99-8a53-f76c7a0d98fe",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/GraphicsServices.framework\/GraphicsServices",
    "name" : "GraphicsServices"
  },


are you able to solve this? I am also getting same error

It won't be possible to reproduce this behaviour without iOS simulator and for that you'll need a Mac.
However, what you can do is integrate logging tools like Firebase Crashlytics or Sentry. This will give you a stack trace of error and in most cases actual line in the code.
Edit: Can you add the crash logs please.

hey i uploadeed part of the crashlog
